# How to animate the evolution of a wavefunction?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, animation

I wanted to show an animation for the time evolution of a function, and I chose the harmonic oscillator because I can write the evolution more easily. When I choose a specific *t* the first graph works great, so I think the temporal evolution works fine. The problem is that the animation is static when I used just *Animate*, and when I use *ListAnimate* I got the image that I will put below. 
In the sum it should have been an exponential, that here it is written with *E* for some reason, at the power -i, that is written with *I*. I don't know why it's written like this when I paste it, but I wanted to specify it to not be any confusion.

```
xM = 20; 
Nx = 1024; 
dx = 2xM / Nx; 
m=1;
\[HBar]=1;
\[Omega] =1;
\[Alpha]=Sqrt[m \[Omega]/\[HBar]];
X = Table[-xM + i * dx, {i,1,Nx}];
\[u][n_,x_]=Sqrt[\[Alpha]/(2^n n! Sqrt[\[Pi]])]HermiteH[n, \[Alpha] x]E^(-\[Alpha]^2 x^2/2);

Ny = 5;
c = 1/(Ny + 1); 
\[CapitalPsi] = Sum[c*\!\(TraditionalForm\`u[j, X]\), {j, 0, Ny}];

Tm = 10;
dt = 1;
En[n_] = \[HBar] \[Omega] (1/2 + n);
\[CapitalPhi] = 
  Sum[E^(-I*En[j]*t)*c*\!\(TraditionalForm\`u[j, X]\), {j, 0, Ny}];
t = 10;

ListLinePlot[{Table[{X[[i]], Abs[\[CapitalPhi][[i]]]^2}, {i, 1, Nx}]},
  PlotRange -> All]

ListAnimate[
 ListLinePlot[{Table[{X[[i]], Abs[\[CapitalPhi][[i]]]^2}, {i, 1, 
     Nx}]}, PlotRange -> All], {t, 0, Tm, dt}, 
 AnimationRunning -> False]
```

[image: The image that I talked about in the beginning]

Comment: For a start, change \[u][n_,x_] to u[n_,x_] and remove the backslash in front of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
xM = 20;
Nx = 1024;
dx = 2 xM/Nx;
m = 1;
ℏ = 1;
ω = 1;
α = Sqrt[m ω/ℏ];
X = Table[-xM + i*dx, {i, 1, Nx}];
u[n_, x_] = 
  Sqrt[α/(2^n n! Sqrt[π])] HermiteH[n, α x] E^(-α^2 x^2/2);

Ny = 5;
c = 1/(Ny + 1);
Ψ = Sum[c*u[j, X], {j, 0, Ny}];

Tm = 10;
dt = 1;
En[n_] = ℏ ω (1/2 + n);

Φ[t_] = Sum[E^(-I*En[j]*t)*c*u[j, X], {j, 0, Ny}];
```

Using [`Table`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) to build the data for the plot is highly inefficient

```
AbsoluteTiming[
  data1[t_] = Table[{X[[i]], Abs[Φ[t][[i]]]^2}, {i, 1, Nx}];][[1]]

(* 25.0747 *)

AbsoluteTiming[data2[t_] = Transpose[{X, Abs[Φ[t]]^2}];][[1]]

(* 0.028742 *)

data1[t] === data2[t]

(* True *)

ListLinePlot[data2 /@ {0, 5, 10}, PlotRange -> All,
 PlotLegends -> Placed[
   LineLegend[{0, 5, 10},
    LegendLabel -> Style[HoldForm@t, 14]], {.8, .5}]]
```

[image]

```
ListAnimate[
 Table[
  ListLinePlot[data2[t], PlotRange -> All],
  {t, 0, Tm, dt}],
 AnimationRunning -> False]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Your calculation is a bit lengthy, so it is better to prepare all the plots, then plot them. Here is one way to do this:

**Define a function to calculate the wave function at time t**

```
mkWaveFunction[t_] := (
   xM = 20; 
   Nx = 1024; 
   dx = 2 xM / Nx; 
   m = 1;
   ℏ = 1;
   ω = 1;
   α = Sqrt[m ω/ℏ];
   X = Table[-xM + i * dx, {i, 1, Nx}];
   u[n_, x_] = 
     Sqrt[α/(2^n n! Sqrt[π])] HermiteH[n, α x] E^(-α^2 x^2/2);
   
   Ny = 5;
   c = 1/(Ny + 1); 
   Ψ = Sum[c*u[j, X], {j, 0, Ny}];
   
   Tm = 10;
   dt = 1;
   En[n_] = ℏ ω (1/2 + n);
   Φ = Sum[E^(-I*En[j]*t)*c*u[j, X], {j, 0, Ny}];
   );
```

**Generate a table of plots at t=0...10**

```
myListOfPlots = Table[mkWaveFunction[t];
   Print["making plot at t = ", t];
   ListLinePlot[{Table[{X[[i]], Abs[Φ[[i]]]^2}, {i, 1,Nx}]}, 
     PlotRange -> All], {t, 0, 10, 1}];
```

This will print the progress as the plots are generated.

**Animate the list of plots**

```
ListAnimate[myListOfPlots]
```

This should produce the animation you want

[image]

**To save as animated GIF**

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]
Export["animation.gif", myListOfPlots, "DisplayDurations" -> 1]
```

Comment: Why do you put everything in the first part in the function "mkWaveFunction[t];". Like, the constants and the table for X?

Comment: I put inside the function everything you need to calculate `X` and `Φ` to generate a plot. You can take things out of the function if you want (try it) or you can modify the function to take parameters like `Nx` as arguments.